# Simplex Method and Unrestricted Variables

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, simplex

I was hoping someone here could explain this issue: say you are working with a set of linear equations in standard form
($a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 + a_3 x_3 + \ldots + a_n x_n= c$ where $c$ is the constant), and for all $k$, $x_k$ is *unrestricted* - meaning that it could be positive or negative (each variable is over the Rationals $\mathbb{Q}$).

Simplex-based algorithms with pivoting rules like [Robert Bland's finite method](http://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/moor.2.2.103?journalCode=moor) usually only work with *positive* variables, so we need to fix this. The traditional solution has been to replace $x_k$ with $\delta_{(x,k,+)} - \delta_{(x,k,-)}$, where $\delta_{(x,k,+)}$ represents the positive component of $x$, and the other the negative component. Each $\delta$ is strictly positive, thus allowing us to solve with it.

The implementation I've looked at makes a *summation* of all the error variables as the objective function - this is intuitive if you're trying to minimize the *change* in the basic-feasible solution. For instance, if you use the dual simplex method to minimize the error variables over their constraint set, then you're basically trying to bring the *unrestricted* variables closer to 0 in the objective function, which is actually minimizing the changes needed to be made in the constraint set (which, if you recall what a [basic-feasible solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm#Overview) is - we ignore the objective function's value).

My question is this - would the primal simplex method (maximization) have a similar effect? I first thought that it would try to change the unrestricted variables, but then I realized that maximizing them would still cause the net-worth of the unrestricted variable to hit 0 (because a large amount minus itself is still 0).

By turning the unrestricted variables into two error variables, the objective function then has this strange $\sum^n_{k=1} {\big(\delta_{(x,k,+)} + \delta_{(x,k,-)}\big)} = 0$ behavior - I'm now not sure what the effect of maximization or minimization would have on the unrestricted scenario - we would maximize or minimize *both* variables by the same amount, where the value of $x$ is the *difference* of the two.

My guess is that primal simplex "puts values where the should be", while dual simplex "moves them as little as possible".

Comment: I seem to be missing something here. Why are you using the simplex method on a set of linear *equations* on unrestricted variables? It's just a linear system.

Comment: Here's the thing: you can actually apply the simplex method to a problem with unrestricted variables. To do so, *you include them in the initial basis, and you never remove them.* Which means that at every step in the simplex, you're solving a linear system involving those variables. If there are no *other* variables, you're done in one step.

Comment: I can't really understand this question.. maybe more context and a clear formulation of the problem would help.